# Fetching records using query in batches from db2

Tags: sql, select, db2

Please let me know if there is any query which can fetch records in batches from db2...
for example if there are 10,000 records in table, I need to fetch first 1000 records and then next 1000 records in each query until end of the table.
I'm looking for a query not stored procedure with cursors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM 
   ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col2) AS rowNum, col2, col1 
     FROM  <schema>.table1) AS tab 
WHERE rowNum between 1 and 500
```

Here rowNum can be modified to fetch all records once we have total record count.

col2 can be identified preferably like creation/update timestamp which can be used to order records ascending/descending. It can be any other column as well for ordering records logically.